# Add the link to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask in the "How to Ask" block

Tags: feature-request, blocks

On Stack Overflow, the "How to Ask" block shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask contains a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, which is not present on Drupal Answers.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

It would be good if the same link would be present in Drupal Answers too.

As I am writing this question, Drupal Answers' revision is 2012.7.12.3332; Stack Overflow's revision is 2012.7.12.3332.